# Using ICompilationUnit for ASTParser.setSource() method in eclipse jdt/ast

Tags: java, eclipse, methods, abstract-syntax-tree, eclipse-jdt

ASTParser.setSource has polymorphic methods with different input types.

[image]

However, when I use `ICompilationUnit` as an input to setSource method,

[image]

I got an error saying I didn't use char[] as an input parameter.

[image]

Why this error?

### ADDED

I use eclipse jdt/ast as a part of stand alone java program. In the course of doing that, I don't use eclipse project/resources, but load the java source into char[] as a parameter for setSource(). I'm not sure, but the eclipse may recognize that it's not run as a plugin to block the usage of other polymorphic methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was trying to execute the jdt/ast as a library for stand-alone java program. When I rerun them in plugin context, everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

check whether you have specified the kind as compilation unit.

```
// Parse the class as a compilation unit.
parser.setKind(ASTParser.K_COMPILATION_UNIT);
```

Comment: Yes I did, and you can see that it is specified to K_COMPILATION_UNIT in the screen capture.